# SSMS Backup Set list - What is supposed to show here?

Tags: sql-server

I use SSMS Maintenance Plan to run 3 backup tasks:

1. Full backup - each week
2. Differential backup - each day
3. Transaction log backup - each 15 minutes

The routine is up and running for the last 3 months.
When I go the my database, in the Restore GUI, I only see one **one Full backup** and **one Differential backup**. **Is this the expected?** Or should I be able to see all the Full, Differential and Transaction backups that exist on my hard disk?

[image: Print screen of my SSMS Restore GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the Restore GUI, I only see one one Full backup and one
> Differential backup. Is this the expected?

This page shows you how to restore to the point you set in "Restore to".

Choose another date and you'll see other backups.
The shortest way to restore your database to today's date is to restore the nearest `full backup` (2020-11-01) + latest `differential` (2020-11-06) + some `log backups` to desired point in time, that's why they are shown up.